# syntax for specifying matched digit string in Emacs replace-regexp?

Tags: regex, emacs

In Emacs, I'm trying to prepend instances of digits with a text string, so that every `</a>1</h2>` will become `</a>Chapter 1</h2>` and so on.

I'm able to find matches using this regexp: `</a>\([0-9]+\)`

How do I specify the existing matched digit in my replacement string, rather than the entire string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly used the `\(` and `\)` to enclose the digits in a capture group which you can write into the replacement string with `\1` (since that is the first capture group) in your regex.  So your replacement string would be

```
</a>Chapter \1
```